# how to create a countdown in my web application?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying get a counter to work in PHP so it basically counts '5' then '4' and so on till 0. It will redirect to a different page. I was just wondering how this can be done in PHP? if possible, if not what it would be in javascript?

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript. Also, this can be done with plain JavaScript, it is not hard to search for.

Comment: You should try do some research, test a few things and post code that you are having problems with.

Comment: Counting down in PHP is an entirely different proposition from counting down in javascript. See also: `setTimeout` for javascript, `sleep` and `for/while` for PHP, and Google for basic and general questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Techniques). Other than that … you should really try to do *some* original research yourself and ask meaningful questions if you are stuck by illustrating your problem and showing us your current solution/approach.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will redirect after 5 seconds:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "newpage.html"; 
    }, 5000); //seconds
</script>
```

here's a example of count down timer: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/)